# Getting values from objects that are in an array of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's say I have an array like so...

```
const myCustomers = [
    {
        accounts: [
            {
                accountID: 1234
            },
            {
                acountID: 2345
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        accounts: [
            {
                accountID: 3456
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        accounts: [
            {
                accountID: 4567
            },
            {
                accountID: 5678
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I'm basically just trying to create an array of all the accountIDs, so it looks something like this...

```
const accountIDs = [1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678];
```

I've tried using map but I'm not having luck.

```
const myRes = myCustomers.map(a => a.accounts.accountID);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
myCustomers.map(c => c.accounts).flat().map(c => c.accountID)
```

DEMO:

```js
const myCustomers=[{accounts:[{accountID:1234},{accountID:2345}]},{accounts:[{accountID:3456}]},{accounts:[{accountID:4567},{accountID:5678}]}];  
const result = myCustomers.map(c => c.accounts).flat().map(c => c.accountID);
console.log( result )
```

Or, a better approach using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
myCustomers.flatMap(c => c.accounts).map(c => c.accountID)
```

The `flatMap()` method basically first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a `map()` followed by a `flat()`, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

DEMO:

```js
const myCustomers=[{accounts:[{accountID:1234},{accountID:2345}]},{accounts:[{accountID:3456}]},{accounts:[{accountID:4567},{accountID:5678}]}];  
const result = myCustomers.flatMap(c => c.accounts).map(c => c.accountID);
console.log( result )
```

Comment: Thanks... this did exactly what I needed.